# How can I set the click event of a button to a function in the MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class that grabs an image from an API, manipulates it, then returns it inside a button.

I have another class that calls this, and places a set of these image/buttons into an appropriate Grid, which is placed inside my MainWindow

I want to have the Click on the button collapse the image grid and show a different grid that has an enlarged image. I can't work out how to attach the Click though.

In my image class, I have this to setup the image

```
internal System.Windows.Controls.Button SetupImage()
{
    // Create and manipulate image
    System.Windows.Controls.Image _Image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    this.CreateBitmapImage();
    Bitmap _Bitmap = this.CreateBitmap();
    if (_Bitmap.Width < _Bitmap.Height)
    {
        _Bitmap = this.RotateImage(_Bitmap, 90);
    }
    this.ConvertBitmap(_Bitmap);
    _Image.Source = this.BitmapImage;

    // Create a Button to put the Image in
    System.Windows.Controls.Button _ImageButton = new Button();
    _ImageButton.Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("ButtonTransparent");
    _ImageButton.Content = _Image;

    // HOW DO I DO THIS BIT HERE? =========
    _ImageButton.Click += Application.Current.MainWindow.btnImage_Click;
    // ====================================

    return _ImageButton;
}
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs I have a function that the click should call

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the image clicked on and show the zoomed image version
/// </summary>
private void btnImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Image _ButtonImage = (System.Windows.Controls.Image)((Button)sender).Content;
    imgZoomImage.Source = image.Source;
    grdDetails.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    grdZoomImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

edit:

Some more code to show the full flow.

In MainWindow.xaml.cs the Grid is built

```
grdImages.Children.Clear();
if (_TrayImages != null && _TrayImages.Count > 0)
{
    Grid _ImageGrid = new Grid();
    _ImageGrid = this.ImageGridGenerator.Build(_TrayImages);
    grdImages.Children.Add(_ImageGrid);
}
```

The ImageGridGenerator has code like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Call a Grid Builder function appropriate for the number of images
/// </summary>
internal Grid Build(List<myImage> myImages)
{
    Grid _ImageGrid = new Grid();

    switch (myImages.Count())
    {
        case 1:
            this.BuildOneImageGrid(ref _ImageGrid, myImages[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            this.BuildTwoImageGrid(ref _ImageGrid, myImages);
            break;
        case 3:
            this.BuildThreeImageGrid(ref _ImageGrid, myImages);
            break;
        default:
            // do the default action
            break;
    }

    return _ImageGrid;
}

/// <summary>
/// Create a Grid with one image
/// </summary>
private void BuildOneImageGrid(ref Grid imageGrid, MyImage myImage)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Button _ImageButton = myImage.SetupImage();

    _ImageButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    imageGrid.Children.Add(_ImageButton);
}
```

Comment: Is ICommand to you not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Add an EventHandler to your image class, handle the click in your image class and pass the arguments up to whoever attaches to your EventHandler.

In your image class:

```
public event EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> ImageClicked;

private void OnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ImageClicked != null)
        ImageClicked(sender, e);
}
```

Attach OnClicked to the Clicked event for your Image class.

You can now attach your handler in MainWindow.xaml.cs to your Image events.

Comment: Thanks, but the MainWindow.xaml doesn't have anything in it I can attach to. I'll add some more of my code as an edit.

Comment: @mike, in that case, you can attach to the Images' handlers in the MainWindow.xaml.cs.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to get the EventHandler to attach as per the answer from @Kyhad

So setup the Clicks in MainWindow.xaml.cs by looping through everything in the grid that was returned by my ImageGridGenerator

```
Grid _ImageGrid = new Grid();
_ImageGrid = this.ImageGridGenerator.Build(Images);

// Attach click events
foreach (System.Windows.Controls.Button _ImageButton in _ImageGrid.Children)
{
    _ImageButton.Click += btnImage_Click;
}
grdImages.Children.Add(_ImageGrid);
```

This isn't perfect, but it works.